# Отслеживание slideDown/Up событийJQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Есть блок. При его наведении, в нём же, появляется скрытый блок с функционалом. Для отображения я использую slideDown/Up в JQuery.
Код JS:

```
$('li.block').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('div.info-block').slideDown();
}, function () {
    $(this).find('div.info-block').slideUp();
});
```

И я заметил такую штуку. Если часто наводить и отводить курсор с блока то то что ещё не выполнилось, а именно slideDown/Up будут выполнятся столько раз сколько мы навели. Пример, для пояснения - навожу и убираю быстро 10 раз. Потом убираю курсор и пока этот блок не сделает slideDown/Up 10 раз он не остановится.

Вопрос. как такое можно поправить?

Comment: Попробуйте задать временную задержку для повторений: например, код активируется при каждом наведении, но не чаще чем раз в 100 мс (примерно).

Comment: @aleks.andr делать при помощи setTimeout? не совсем понимаю как такое сделать... не могли бы пример привести?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

остановите предыдущую анимацию, перед началом новой

```
$('li.block').hover(function () {
$(this).find('div.info-block').stop().slideDown();
}, function () {
$(this).find('div.info-block').stop().slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 2:

Я попробовал сделать это при помощи mouseenter и mouseleave и вот что получилось:

```
$('li.block').mouseenter(function () {

    var info-block = $(this).find('div.info-block');

    if(info-block.hasClass('slide-up')) {
        info-block.addClass('no-trans').slideDown(100);
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        info-block.removeClass('slide-up').addClass('slide-down');
    }, 50);

});

$('li.block').mouseleave(function () {

    var info-block= $(this).find('div.info-block');

    if(info-block.hasClass('slide-down')) {
        info-block.slideUp(100);

        setTimeout(function () {
            info-block.removeClass('slide-down').addClass('slide-up');
        }, 50);
    }

});
```

НО. это тоже работает не очень корректно. Если быстро провести по блоку то скрытый блок появится и не пропадёт. Остаётся решить это.. вопрос как...